# Keyboard input not displayed on the screen?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, terminal, keyboard

We use the `exceed tool to connect to our UNIX servers, but sometimes the command-line behaves erratically. When I am typing some command on the command-line, nothing happens -- nothing is displayed on the screen and I need to close the terminal and open a new one. Why does that happen?

Is it related to `stty sane`? I have typed `stty sane` thinking that it is used when your command-line starts behaving erratically; is that what it's for?

Comment: is it like refresh done in windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is what is happening in your case, but pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> will freeze the tty, causing no updates to happen, though your commands are still going through.  To unfreeze the tty, you need to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

Again, I'm not totally sure this is what is happening in your case, but I do this by accident often enough, that it is possible it may affect others as well.

Comment: unfreeze is "Ctrl + q". Are you a Dvorak user too? :-)

Comment: perfect it works(ctrl + s to freeze and ctrl+q to unfreeze), thanks